# In Brunch.io, how do we run tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, coffeescript, brunch

In an application generated by Brunch.io, how do we run tests? I would like to run them via the command line.

For eg., the [todos](https://github.com/brunch/todos) application has quite exhaustive test coverage. But its Cakefile is empty. When I run 'cake test', it doesn't do anything.
Can someone please point me in the right direction on the setup work needed to run the tests (either on command line or on browser)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no official way to run tests in brunch 0.9.

But brunch 1.0 will introduce full support of testing with Mocha and cakefiles.

So you're doing the right thing.

Comment: Waiting eagerly for brunch 1.0

Comment: So with v1.2.2 out now, where's a good example/tutorial for this? There's nothing in the docs yet, and I'd like to get off on the right foot :)

Comment: Not with 1.2, but with 1.3. You can simply do `brunch test` now. Example of test infrastructure: https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin/tree/master/test

Comment: Small side note: I've been looking for a way to automatically require all tests modules with something like `require('test/models')` and it looks like support to see what modules have been defined it coming in 1.7: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/530

Comment: With brunch 2.8 there is again no way to run tests directly from node.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [coffee-purist-brunch](https://github.com/cbosco/coffee-purist-brunch) :

> With this skeleton, run **`npm test`** instead of `brunch test` or **`npm start`** in addition to `brunch watch` in order to automatically run tests. This runs the tests directly on the coffeescript files in `test/` and utilizes NPM-installed test libraries instead of static ones from `test/vendor/` as other skeletons do.

And [brunch-dutch-baby](https://github.com/jkingyens/brunch-dutch-baby) uses Karma.